# Media.setLooping isn't worktin [Android]

Tags: android, audio, background

Hello guys i need some help with my android project :) I want when i press a button to play a sound , but i don't want this sound to end , I want it to repeat.This is my code :

```
package projectill.mrme4ka.org.projectill;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements
View.OnClickListener{          

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void onClick(View v){};

public void buttonBtn (View v){

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.wavsp);
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

It is working but it doesn't play it again. It doesn't loop it. Help me please :) + Can u help me adding OFF button to that sound , if not i will do it myself , but i dont know why the looping is not working

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but you may be calling `start()` and `setLooping()` before the MediaPlayer has been prepared.  MediaPlayer objects are state machines and must be handled carefully (see the [State Diagram here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram)).

Try this instead:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, R.drawable.wavsp);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: I should add - using `prepareAsync()` instead of `create()` will have the added benefit of not blocking your UI thread while the MediaPlayer is prepared.  Since you're not doing this in an `AsyncTask`, this is a better choice.